# Vanilla JS: Select all elements with class within parent based on cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, closest

I have several elements with the class `parent`. These always have the same children: `child` and within the `child` multiple elements with the class `detail`. I always want to read out all the elements with class `detail` within the closest `.parent .child` based on my current cursor position.

Using `document.querySelectorAll('.details');` I get all of them, which is wrong. I tried to use `closest()`, `find()` and `parent()`, but I can't figure out how. Always get follow error in the console: `"Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).closest is not a function"`.

**Workflow:** Basically, when I click into one of the inputs with class `detail` and then hit the `button` below, it should show me all elements with class `detail` within the closest `.parent .child`. E.g When I click into the first `input` and hit the `button`, I should get 3 elements `detail` in my `console.log()`. Use pure `JavaScript`.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('select-detail');

btn.addEventListener('click', getDetails);

function getDetails() {
  // Wrong: selects all elements with detail class
  const detailsAll = document.querySelectorAll('.detail');
  
  // My failed attempt:
  const details = document.querySelectorAll('.detail').closest('.parent .child');
  
  /* Some other failed attempts */
  // const details = document.closest('.detail .child').find('.detail');
  // const details = document.querySelectorAll('.detail').parent('.parent .child');
  
  console.log('details', details);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid lightcoral;
  padding: 5px;
}

.detail {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}

#select-detail {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="select-detail">Select all details of nearest parent to cursor position (open inspector to check)</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the `focusout` event. If the element that triggered the event was a `.detail`, set that element to a persistent variable. Then, in the button click handler, examine what's in the persistent variable, access its `parentElement`, and from there, the `children`, to get all siblings of the most recently blurred input:

```js
let lastFocused;
window.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  const { target } = e;
  if (target.matches('.detail')) {
    lastFocused = target;
  }
});

const btn = document.getElementById('select-detail');

btn.addEventListener('click', getDetails);

function getDetails(e) {
  const theseSiblings = lastFocused.parentElement.children;
  console.log(theseSiblings);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid lightcoral;
  padding: 5px;
}

.detail {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}

#select-detail {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="select-detail">Select all details of nearest parent to cursor position (open inspector to check)</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remember the last `input` you were in, since clicking the button takes the focus away from the input.

```
let input = null;

document.addEventListener("focusin", ({target}) => {
  if (target.tagName === "INPUT") {
    input = target;
  }
});

btn.addEventListener('click', getDetails);

function getDetails() {
  if (!input) {
    console.log("No 'last input'");
    return;
  }
  const details = input.closest('.parent .child');

  console.log('details', details);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('select-detail');

let input = null;

document.addEventListener("focusin", ({target}) => {
  if (target.tagName === "INPUT") {
    input = target;
  }
});

btn.addEventListener('click', getDetails);

function getDetails() {
  if (!input) {
    console.log("No 'last input'");
    return;
  }
  const details = input.closest('.parent .child');
  
  console.log('details', details);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid lightcoral;
  padding: 5px;
}

.detail {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}

#select-detail {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="detail" placeholder="click into input">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="select-detail">Select all details of nearest parent to cursor position (open inspector to check)</button>
```